# nvm is not compatible with the npm config

Tags: npm, nvm

I have node version v14.4.0 and npm version 6.14.5 ,
when I tried to switch to different version using

`nvm install v11.0.0`

and then

`nvm use v11.0.0`

It showed me following error

> ```
> nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""  
> Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v11.0.0` to unset it.
> ```

I tried running those commands but the problem still persists.

Also when tried the command 
`nvm use`
 , It showed

> `No .nvmrc file found`